# Can I have a WHILE loop within a CASE statement?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2014

I wanted to select the data according to the `CASE` statement. Example is given below

```
select Id, name, address,
      case when 
           department = CIS then @first
           else @firstnew
      end as "Date"
```

here the `@first` should be the output of the query below

```
 DECLARE @first date, @second date, @current date, @new date;
 SET @second='2015-12-15'
 SET @new='2015-08-10'
 SET @current = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),110)
 SET @first = '2015-08-15'
 WHILE @first <= @second
 BEGIN
     SET @first = @new
     WHILE @first <= @second
     BEGIN
         if @first >= @current
         break;
         SET @first = DATEADD(MONTH,1,@first)
     END;
     break;
 END;
```

Is it possible to use the above query output `@first`'s value as the result of the first `SELECT` statement if the case that department is equal to CIS?

Comment: I believe you can find out @first value without that ugly while loop...

Comment: @Giorgi Nakeuri didnt get the correct answer that is why I made another question explaining my senario

Comment: You should edit this question rather then add new one. And you can comment to the answer and elaborate what is wrong with it.

Comment: ok I have edited that question pls change as it is not duplicated now..

Answer (score 1):

I think `@firstnew` is equal to `DATEADD(MONTH, -1, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@second), MONTH(@second), DAY(@new)))`, So your query can be like this:

```
SELECT Id, name, address,
    CASE WHEN department = 'CIS' THEN 
        @first
    CASE WHEN @first > @second THEN
        @first
    CASE WHEN @new > @second THEN
        @new
    CASE WHEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@second), MONTH(@second), DAY(@new)) < @second THEN
        DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@second), MONTH(@second), DAY(@new))
    ELSE
        DATEADD(MONTH, -1, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@second), MONTH(@second), DAY(@new)))
    END AS [Date]
...
```